# Eclipse graphical layout size

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, graphical-layout-editor

My graphical layout is really small for some reason and it doesn't scale correctly.Does anyone have this problem or know how to fix it?

I don't have enough rep to upload an image so I had to make a link for it.

Here's what it looks like:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2agtdmr.jpg

Comment: have you find answer??

Comment: @Prag's no I haven't found the answer yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. There may be solution for you...hope it will work...

at the TOP side of you graphical layout screen...there is OPTION for Device screen selection in ***`Configuration chooser`***...

Look here for more help "http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html"

you have selected **"Android wear Round"** screen that may be around 2.7"

Instead of that select **"Nexus One".. which screen size is 3.7" (480 x 800 hdpi)**
it will set your layout to bigger size...

**Changing a device screen can make difference...**

See The Preview Below....

[image]

This may help you thanks...